# $\prod_{k=1}^n k\ \ \equiv 1 \bmod{n}$ where $gcd(k,n)=gcd(k+1,n)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, products

Let 
$$E_n = \left\{ k \in \mathbb{Z}\ \ | \ \ gcd(k,n) = gcd(k+1,n) = 1\wedge 1\le k\le n\right\}$$
I'd like to show that for $n > 2$ :

$$\prod_{k=1,\ k \in E_n}^n k\quad \equiv \quad 1\ \ \bmod{n}$$ There is probably an argument along the lines of $\forall k\exists! m$ such that $km\equiv 1\bmod{n}$, but I don't exactly know how to find that $m$.

Comment: I know how to compute $\sum_{k=1}^n \chi(k) \chi(k+1)$ using the discrete Fourier transform of Dirichlet characters, but not $\sum_{k=1}^n \chi(k) \chi(k+1) \log k$ (here $\chi(k) = 1_{gcd(n,k)=1}$ is the trivial character modulo $n$)

Comment: Where does it come from ? And did you try it for a few $n$ ?

Comment: Niven and Zuckerman Problem 2.2.48 on page 27.

Comment: And what is the context, the chapter ?

Comment: It's on congruences, nothing fancy.